# Updating HTML string containing a variable after the variable is updated in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I'm trying to create a website which uses jQuery to update a div to display a message which uses variable values which are updated only after a button is clicked.

I'm creating a full name by randomly selecting from a list of firstname objects and lastname objects. The first name determines the age of the individual, and the last name determines what text appears. However, sometimes that text includes their first and last name (Ex: `"Hi, I am " + fullname + ". Nice to meet you."`) . For practical purposes, the jQuery is set up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var firstname_list = [];
    var lastname_list = [];
    var fullname;
    function firstname(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        firstname_list.push(this);
    }
    function lastname(name, quote) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quote = quote;
        lastname_list.push(this);
    }
    var MIKE = new firstname("Mike ", "23");
    var BRAD = new firstname("Brad ", "28");
    var JOEY = new firstname("Joey ", "13");
    var DIAZ = new lastname("Diaz", "Hi, my name is " + fullname + ". Nice to meet you.");
    var SMITH= new lastname("Smith", "Hey. What's up?");
    $('button').click(function() {
        var fetched_firstname = firstname_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstname_list.length)];
        var fetched_lastname = lastname_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastname_list.length)];
        fullname = (fetched_firstname['name'] + fetched_lastname['name']);
        $('#quote_div').html(fetched_lastname['quote']);
    }
}
```

And let's say there's a portion of the HTML that looks like this:

```
<div id="quote_div">THE QUOTE GOES HERE AFTER THE BUTTON IS CLICKED</div>
```

When the button is clicked, a random First and Last name are generated. However, if the last name's `['quote']` property contains `+ fullname +` as part of the string (if the lastname is "Diaz"), it will print "undefined" instead of the concatenated full name I created in the jQuery button click event. I'm assuming that this is because the object is created before the button is ever clicked, and the button's script doesn't retroactively let the object's `['quote']` property value know that `fullname` has been updated.

How can I work around this? I need the user to be able to keep clicking the randomizing button to generate new name combinations, so I can't load everything when the DOM is ready.

Comment: You want a random first AND random last name to populate into a `div`? I can help if that's your end game.

Comment: At no point above `i, my name is " + fullname + ". Nic...` did you ever change `fullname` from an undefined variable, thus JS only sees it as that. Had `fullname` been defined before `DIAZ` was made, it would be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to do something like this:

```
var DIAZ = new lastname("Diaz", "Hi, my name is %fullname% Nice to meet you.");

 $('#quote_div').html(fetched_lastname['quote'].replace('%fullname%', fullname ));
```

Comment: Hey, that works! I didn't know about the .replace() method. This helps get around the problem of DIAZ trying to reference a variable before it has been appropriately defined.

Answer (score 0):

## Well, here's my take on it:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/Z92bd/1/

**Sorry to rewrite everything, but why not keep all your names in arrays so you CAN load it before the `DOM`...?** You could always make a large object as well if you'd prefer to maintain `ages` and whatnot.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="makeName">Make Name</button>
<div id="display">
```

**Javascript**

```
var first = ['sally', 'jacob', 'matt', 'joseph'];
var last = ['johnson', 'haahr', 'hazel', 'garcias'];

$('#makeName').on('click', function() {
    var f = Math.floor(Math.random() * first.length );
    var l = Math.floor(Math.random() * first.length );
    $('#display').text("Hi, my name is " + first[f] + " " + last[l] + ", nice to meet you!");
});
```

Comment: I didn't do it like this because I needed the actual text of the quote (which may or may not include the full name) to be tied to the randomized last name, for reasons that go beyond this question.

Comment: Understandably so :-) I looked back afterwards and realized I probably only answered the surface of the question. I'll leave it up for reference, but I don't think this helps you much based on your use-case. Best of luck!